Why are we having an election?
An election was just announced: Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2024, however no explanation was given about the reason for this election.
We already had an election in 2022 and we have three diamond moderators. Why do we need two more? I can see that Eric was "last seen 3 months ago", and that Couchy hasn't written a post since 2022, but if that's the reason why two more diamond moderators are going to be added to the team, why are two not being removed?
Can the diamond moderation team please explain when and why they requested for two more to be added, and if this request was made by one, two, or all of the current diamond moderators?

I inferred that the two less active moderators are to be removed after the election (based on moderator chats and this announcement), but perhaps it's best for SE staff to clarify this.

Yes, I haven't been active in a while and will be stepping down. I think it's reasonable to switch up moderators every few years
